# Scroll to top script not working in conjunction with overflow:scroll

Tags: javascript, css

I wrote this scroll to top script. Everything works great but not with overflow:scroll which I have applied to my wrapper div. The reason I need overflow:scroll is because I have overflow:hidden for html/body tag. This is neccesary for my custom scrollbar to function at best. I am aware that this interferes with this script, but why?

The script works only partially well. The "scroll to top" appears when scrolling down, but after clicking it, it wont go to the top.

What am I doing wrong?

**This is the Javascript:**

```
<script>            
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            var offset = 220;
            var duration = 500;
            jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
                if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
                    jQuery('.back-to-top').fadeIn(duration);
                } else {
                    jQuery('.back-to-top').fadeOut(duration);
                }
            });

            jQuery('.back-to-top').click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                jQuery('#wrapper').animate({scrollTop: 0}, duration);
                return false;
            })
        });
    </script>
```

**My CSS**

```
<style>
        .back-to-top {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 2em;
            right: 0px;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #000000;
            background-color: rgba(235, 235, 235, 0.80);
            font-size: 12px;
            padding: 1em;
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
```

**and finally this is the Html:**

```
<a href="#" class="back-to-top">Back to Top</a>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your javascript console?

Comment: Seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/L86yf/2/ (slightly adjusted)

Comment: No errors in firebug, everything is fine.

Comment: What is your reasoning for putting `return false;` after the animation?

Answer (score 0):

You problem is here:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > offset) { }
});
```

What you do is checking if the "window" object was scrolled and if current top offset is bigger than "offset" variable, but then you try to scroll inside of "#wrapper".

What you should do is checking if "#wrapper" was scrolled and if it reached the offset.

EDIT: If you want to scroll the "window" object, you should animate "body" DOM element like below ;)

```
$('body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, duration);
```